# SQLite obtaining Query Data problems

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have an app that saves user profile images in one table and there names in another, in the image table I keep the user_id as foreign Key, the issue here is when obtaining the user image and name I want to get the user stored in the image table as foreign key, every time I try to get it I get a nullPointer, below is my code, thanks in advance.

```
 getDataQuery = "SELECT "+userId+", "+username +", "+userImg +" FROM " +
            ""+userTable+" left join  "+imageTable +" on "+userId +" = "+imageFK_id;
```

So in this case I want to get the `imageFK_id as well`

Comment: Can you provide what the final result of the variable getDataQuery holds before executing, along with the table structures and some sample values of whatever userTable and imageTable hold values for?  An [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5) would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ' before and after imageFK_id, like this:

```
getDataQuery = "SELECT "+userId+", "+username +", "+userImg +" FROM " +
        ""+userTable+" left join  "+imageTable +" on "+userId +" = '"+imageFK_id +"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized am only getting rows whose `imageFK_id = userId` so I just got the value being held by `userId`, Thank you everybody for your help